# Setting up phone number format while typing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am setting phone number format such as (222) 233-3441 while typing in textField. When user keeps entering more that 14 characters (including special characters), all special characters will be removed and numbers alone be displayed (i.e. 222233344188). And when they reach back to 14 characters on deleting some characters, the phone number format will be set again. I achieved as i wanted. But facing problem while deleting.

- While deleting - format is being applied when number of character reach to 10. So 2222333441 becomes (222) 233-3441.
- Keep deleting, getting looped since format getting applied and the character reach to 10 again.

Became blank to move forward. Please push me up with your valuable suggestions to resolve this issue.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


    if(string.length!=0){   //detect backspace

        if (textField.text.length == 0)
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@",textField.text];

        if (textField.text.length == 4)
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@) ",textField.text];

        if (textField.text.length == 9)
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",textField.text];

        if (textField.text.length>13){

            NSString *value=[NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
            textField.text=[[value componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        }
    }
    else{

        if(textField.text.length==11){

            NSMutableString *text=[NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];
            [text insertString:@"(" atIndex:0];
            [text insertString:@") " atIndex:4];
            [text insertString:@"-" atIndex:9];
            textField.text=text;
        }

     }

     return YES;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is your app going to be available outside of the USA and Canada? If so, you need to handle a lot more phone formats that this.

Comment: From UX perspective, I recommend setting up phone format when user is done with typing (i.e. when keyboard resigns). Also, if possible, complement this format in the `placeholder` text as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments, i.e. this is not advisable design.

Still, the programming question is interesting. My approach would be to first "normalize" the text, i.e. remove all non-numeric characters and then apply your logic.

```
textField.text=[[textField.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
     [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
     componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: That did the trick. worked as i expected. Thank you very much for your   interest and suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest more compact solution:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    BOOL result = YES;
    if (string.length != 0) {
        NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[[textField.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];
        [text insertString:@"(" atIndex:0];

        if (text.length > 3)
            [text insertString:@") " atIndex:4];

        if (text.length > 8)
            [text insertString:@"-" atIndex:9];

        if (text.length > 13) {
            text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[text substringToIndex:14]];
            result = NO;
        }
        textField.text = text;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work when tapping inside the textField to change a current value

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code this might help u a bit

txtlpmobile.text is the string(Mobile no ur gonna enter)

```
 int length = [self getLength:txtLpMobile.text];
            if(length == 10) {
                if(range.length == 0)
                    return NO;
            }
            if(length == 3){
                NSString *num = [self formatNumber:txtLpMobile.text];
                txtLpMobile.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];

                if(range.length > 0) {
                    txtLpMobile.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];

                }
            } else if(length == 6) {
                NSString *num = [self formatNumber:txtLpMobile.text];
                txtLpMobile.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
                if(range.length > 0) {
                    txtLpMobile.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
                }
            }

            NSUInteger newLength;
            newLength = [txtLpMobile.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
            NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS_ONLY] invertedSet];
            NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            return (([string isEqualToString:filtered])&&(newLength <= CHARACTER_LIMIT));
```

for formatting number

```
-(NSString*)formatNumber:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    int length = [mobileNumber length];
    if(length > 10)
    {
        mobileNumber = [mobileNumber substringFromIndex: length-10];
    }
    return mobileNumber;
}
```

for getting length

```
-(int)getLength:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    int length = [mobileNumber length];

    return length;
}
```